# Why does Chrome remove an image pattern on an SVG when using jQuery Draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm wrapping an SVG inside a draggable div. The SVG requires a shape or path with an image fill on the face. Everything renders fine and works 100% in Firefox. In Chrome, it lets you drag once and everything is fine but on subsequent drag operations the image disappears on drop. The weird thing is that the image reappears in the helper and original div on subsequent drag operations but always disappears on drop.

In IE it lets you drag once and then it freezes in place.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="svgcontainer draggable" style="width:300px; height:220px">
    <svg transform="translate(0,0)" viewBox="0 0 8000 8000">
         <defs>
            <rect id="rectangle" width="8000" height="5860" />
            <pattern id="texture" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="8000" height="8000">
                <image xlink:href="http://texturezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Spray-Wall-Texture-01.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="16000" height="8000" transform="translate(-4000,0)" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#rectangle" fill="url(#texture)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.svgcontainer {position:absolute;border:2px solid red;}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.7,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        $(this).css('top', top);
        $(this).css('left', left);
    }
});
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osmybu81/8/

Comment: `width="16000" height="8000"` — is 128 megapixels really necessary? Why not try making this thing a bit smaller?

Comment: I just figured out a fix to make this work in Chrome but it's crazy. It involves copying the contents of the draggable div on the start event and then copying over those contents on the stop event. Basically writing the contents over the same contents. Crazy but it fixes the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Dradge/osmybu81/11/ Still no idea why it freezes in IE.

Comment: @squeamish - the width and height you mention are not pixels. They are the coordinates of my SVG system. The height and width is controlled by the containing div. Check out an explanation here: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use `helper: clone`?  Because if you remove that, it seems to work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/osmybu81/13/

Comment: Unfortunately yes Paul. The customer requested a clone to be dragged around. Good spot though and no clone seems to prevent it locking in IE. I did find a solution that works 100% with a clone in Chrome and FF but the locking up in IE is the only issue now.